# Strange behavior of ListView

Tags: listview, blackberry, qt4, qml, blackberry-10

I am using following code:

```
ListView {
        id: listView 
listItemComponents: ListItemComponent {

            Container {
                id: listItemContainer
                property string packageId: ListItemData.packageId
                property variant packageDetailsPage
                layout: AbsoluteLayout {

                }
                WebImageView {
                    preferredHeight: 290
                    preferredWidth: 751
                    url: ListItemData.url;  



                 }
    }
}
```

**code for WebImageView:**

```
//webimageview.hpp
#ifndef WEBIMAGEVIEW_H_
#define WEBIMAGEVIEW_H_

#include <bb/cascades/ImageView>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkDiskCache>
#include <QUrl>
using namespace bb::cascades;

class WebImageView: public bb::cascades::ImageView {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY (QUrl url READ url WRITE setUrl NOTIFY urlChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY (float loading READ loading NOTIFY loadingChanged)

public:
    WebImageView();
    const QUrl& url() const;
    double loading() const;

    public Q_SLOTS:
    void setUrl(const QUrl& url);
    void clearCache();

    private Q_SLOTS:
    void imageLoaded();
    void dowloadProgressed(qint64,qint64);

    signals:
    void urlChanged();
    void loadingChanged();


private:
    static QNetworkAccessManager * mNetManager;
    static QNetworkDiskCache * mNetworkDiskCache;
    QUrl mUrl;
    float mLoading;    
    bool isARedirectedUrl(QNetworkReply *reply);
    void setURLToRedirectedUrl(QNetworkReply *reply);
};

#endif /* WEBIMAGEVIEW_H_ */
```

**webimageview.cpp**

```
#include "WebImageView.h"
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkDiskCache>
//#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <bb/cascades/Image>

using namespace bb::cascades;

QNetworkAccessManager * WebImageView::mNetManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
//QNetworkDiskCache * WebImageView::mNetworkDiskCache = new QNetworkDiskCache();

WebImageView::WebImageView() {

    mLoading = 0;
}

const QUrl& WebImageView::url() const {
    return mUrl;
}

void WebImageView::setUrl(const QUrl& url) {
    // Variables
        mUrl = url;
        mLoading = 0;
        qDebug()<<"url:: "<<mUrl;
        // Reset the image
        resetImage();

        // Create request
        QNetworkRequest request;
        request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute, QNetworkRequest::PreferCache);
        request.setUrl(url);

        // Create reply
        QNetworkReply * reply = mNetManager->get(request);

        // Connect to signals
        QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(imageLoaded()));
        QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(dowloadProgressed(qint64,qint64)));

        emit urlChanged();

}

double WebImageView::loading() const {
    return mLoading;
}

void WebImageView::imageLoaded() {
    // Get reply
    QNetworkReply * reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
    QObject::disconnect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(imageLoaded()));
    QObject::disconnect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(dowloadProgressed(qint64,qint64)));
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        if (isARedirectedUrl(reply)) {
            setURLToRedirectedUrl(reply);
            return;
        } else {
            QByteArray imageData = reply->readAll();
            setImage(Image(imageData));

        }
    }
    // Memory management
    reply->deleteLater();
}

bool WebImageView::isARedirectedUrl(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    QUrl redirection = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute).toUrl();
    return !redirection.isEmpty();
}

void WebImageView::setURLToRedirectedUrl(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    QUrl redirectionUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute).toUrl();
    QUrl baseUrl = reply->url();
    QUrl resolvedUrl = baseUrl.resolved(redirectionUrl);

    setUrl(resolvedUrl.toString());
}

void WebImageView::clearCache() {
    //mNetworkDiskCache->clear();
}

void WebImageView::dowloadProgressed(qint64 bytes, qint64 total) {
    mLoading = double(bytes) / double(total);

    emit loadingChanged();
}
```

I am using ListDataModel. and above code is working fine and loading images. But when there are more than 100 items in a list it shows wrong images in some WebImageView. when you scroll randomly the images change. I have checked the url property of webImageView in item where wrong image is loaded, but it has the right url.

in this link: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__listview.html
blackberry says that list view follows MVC architecture, and QObject objects owned by ListView are deleted when the item they belong to is scrolled out of the visible area, or when the ListView itself is deleted. is it the cause of my issue?
if no that what is wrong with this code?
please help...

Answer (score 0):

If one image takes too long to load, it will override the new image when the cells is restored.
The method setUrl must start by cancelling the current request if it was loading

```
[In constructor] mNetManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(Application::instance());


void WebImageView::setUrl(const QUrl& url) {
mUrl = url;

//If another URL was loading:
if(reply != 0 && reply->isRunning()){
    disconnect(reply);
    reply->abort();
}

//Chargement
//qDebug() << "WebImageView setUrl " << url;
if(url.isValid() && !url.isEmpty()) {
    if(url.toString().startsWith("asset://")){
        setImageSource(url);
        return;
    }

        setImageSource(mDefaultSource);
        reply = mNetManager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
        connect(reply,SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(imageLoaded()));
}
emit urlChanged();
}
```

Comment: firstly, `mNetManager` is static. intantiating it in contructor may create a problem.

Comment: Whatever you prefer, I choose to instanciate the static on demand if not instanciated yet (and the parent was indeed Application::instance(), not this). Secondly?

Comment: secondly see [this Link] (http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Strange-behavior-of-ListView/m-p/3050220/highlight/false#M70589). I have asked this question on blackberry support forum. have a look.